# C# Change The Form's Back Color With A Button

Tags: c#, forms, button, timer, backcolor

In Visual Studio 2017 Community, how can I change the back colour of the form once a button is pressed? I am trying to make a rainbow form so in that instance I am using a timer.

My code is:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int A = rand.Next(0, 255);
        int R = rand.Next(0, 255);
        int G = rand.Next(0, 255);
        int B = rand.Next(0, 255);
        Form1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work.

[My Error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/542098759811858474/549267995638366255/unknown.png)

Comment: `A` must always be `255` as forms don't support transparent backgrounds

Comment: [this is my error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/542098759811858474/549267995638366255/unknown.png)

Comment: Then try `this.BackColor` instaed of `Form1.BackColor`

Comment: I can't put that in my timer tick code

Comment: Just change the line `Form1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);` to `this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);`

Comment: this worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int A = rand.Next(0, 255);
        int R = rand.Next(0, 255);
        int G = rand.Next(0, 255);
        int B = rand.Next(0, 255);
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
    }
```